# Azure: How to associate a storage account for a specific SQL Database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I would like to know if you are able to select your own storage account when creating a SQL database and SQL server on Azure?  I have tried this a few times and but it doesn't seem to give the option to select an existing storage account.  I am trying to associate specific storage accounts with specific resources using a similar name.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure SQL Database, as a fully managed service, does not expose a Storage Account to you. How it stores its data is not something you have to worry about. You just specify the performance tier and amount of storage to use (and region, security/network settings, etc). That's it.

Same thing applies to SQL Managed Instance service: You can specify amount of storage, and region.

Now: If you create a SQL Server instance within your own VM, then yes, you get to choose every detail, including storage account location (or the use of Managed Disks), medium type (SSD, for example).